# How to access a parent window on Adobe Air Apps

Tags: adobe, air, parent

Following is a sample code for opening a window in Adobe Air App.

```
var init = new air.NativeWindowInitOptions();
var bounds = null;
var child = air.File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('child.html');
bounds = new air.Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 500);
win = air.HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(true, init, false, bounds);
win.load(new air.URLRequest(child.url));
```

A opened window must access document object of a parent window.
Following is a code of child.html

```
<script>

function init() {
    alert(window.parent);
}

</script>

<body onload="init()">
```

this code alerts null message;
Is there no way to access a parent window?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the createRootWindow() function, you get a window without a parent -- that's what the "Root" in the function name is trying to get across (poorly, it seems). It is easy to workaround, though:

```
win = air.HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(true, init, false, bounds);
win.load(new air.URLRequest(child.url));
//add
win.window.parent = this.window;
```

At least that's the general idea. You might need to wait for the htmlDOMCreate  or complete event before setting the parent. Also, AIR might let you set the parent even if the child is in another security sandbox. If so, that would be a big security hole in your app.